# CSS floating div fixed margin-top

Tags: css, css-float, html

how can i fixed the floating div? i have tried margin-top

```
<div id="headerRightContent" style="float: left; height: 100px; margin-top: 105px; width: 1px; whitespace: no-wrap;background-lightyellow;margin:0px 10px 10px 12px;color: #FF00FF;border: 1px dashed black;width: 175px;padding-left:6px;padding-bottom:6px;padding-top:6px;">
```

but did not do any thing, so i have add more content the div on the left is floating down and delete the content the floating goes up...

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/Vmjmz/)

Comment: It seems that the containing `td` has inherited `vertical-align:center` from somewhere, which centers the content vertically. Is this the desired effect: http://jsfiddle.net/Vmjmz/1/ ?

Comment: the content should be align to left but i see your jsfiddle and the content item is in the center and the floating div is all the way up... thats not what i am looking for; based on my sample i am looking to display the floating div `margin-top:100px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues.

**Issue 1:** Your containing `td` is inheriting `vertical-align:middle` from somewhere. You'll need to remove that or override it with `vertical-align:top`.

```
<td style="vertical-align:top;">
```

**Issue 2:** You are setting margin styles twice on your `div`, essentially erasing your `margin-top` setting. Combine them or remove the second one.

```
<div id="headerRightContent" style="float: left; height: 100px; margin:105px 10px 10px 12px; width: 1px; whitespace: no-wrap;background-lightyellow;color: #FF00FF;border: 1px dashed black;width: 175px;padding-left:6px;padding-bottom:6px;padding-top:6px;">
```

Also, I strongly suggest putting your inline styles into an external style sheet.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vmjmz/3/